# GNU Screen prepending dollar signs to window titles

Tags: macos, fedora, gnu-screen

I recently copied my `.screenrc` from one computer (Mac OSX 10.4) to another computer (Fedora 16)

Now, on the Fedora computer, there is a `$` prepended to all the window titles.

Here is my hardstatus line:

```
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g} %{r}%l%{= kG} ][%= %{=kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

I have some screens set up to automatically start.

```
#Default Screens
screen -t foo 0
screen -t bar 1
screen -t fizz 2
screen -t buzz 3
screen -t bag-and-tag 4
screen -t deployment-zone 5
```

But the window titles displayed when I start `screen` have a dollar sign prepended:

```
 (0*$foo)  1$ bar  2$ fizz  3$ buzz  4$ bag-and-tag  5-$ deployment-zone
```

I think this has something to do with the difference in shell environments (Mac OSX Darwin vs. full Linux),

Answer (score 2):

Look under the `windows` command in the documentation and you'll see:

```
 The current window is marked with a `*'; the previous window is
 marked with a `-'; all the windows that are logged in are marked
 with a `$' (*note Login::); a background window that has received
 a bell is marked with a `!'; a background window that is being
 monitored and has had activity occur is marked with an `@' (*note
 Monitor::); a window which has output logging turned on is marked
 with `(L)'; windows occupied by other users are marked with `&' or
 `&&' if the window is shared by other users; windows in the zombie
 state are marked with `Z'.
```

The `$` denotes that a login shell was started.  The terminal session is registered with `who` and `w` and the `~/.bash_profile` would have been run at shell startup.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken you hardstatus string and modified it to take out just the `$` characters:

```
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g} %{r}%l%{= kG} ][%= %{=kw}%?%-w%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+w%?%?%= %{g}][%{B}%Y-%m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

Basically, `$` character was added because `window flags` were on. Here are the excerpts from the above that were changed:

- `%-Lw%` to `%-w%` - Taking `L` character here removes `window flags` for all the windows **before** the currently selected window (win that is marked with *).
- `%+Lw%` to `%-w%` - Same as above for windows **after** the currently selected window.
- `%n*%f%t` to `%n*%t` - selection for currently selected window (notice the `*`)

Here is the reference [link about GNU Screen string escapes](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#String-Escapes) that has more info and explanation about each of the characters from the above string.